# How do I get the information from two tables and add it into a separate table?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to join the tables **Students and Course** and then add a mark (When the add button is pressed) into the table **Student_Course** using the SID (Student ID) and CID (Course ID) combo boxes which are bound to tables SID in Students and CID in Courses .

In the code I've tried to join the tables but it gives me a

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll"` Error. Error occurs where I join the table.

How would I fix this up? Or is there another way to do this?

TLDR;

So I've got two comboboxes called CID and SID where I can select the Course ID and Student ID. Then I have a textbox for Marks. I want to be able to select the Course ID and Student ID and then add the marks to it.

```js
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            int SID = Convert.ToInt32(cboSID.Text);
            int CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboCID.Text);                 

            Student_Course marks = (from c in db.Student_Course join s in db.Students on c.SID equals s.SID join o in db.Courses on c.CID equals o.CID where c.SID == SID && c.CID == CID select c).First();
            marks.Mark = Convert.ToInt32(txtMark.Text);

            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Marks Added");
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2()) //link combobox and DataGridView to List in Student_Course
        {
            var studentCourse = from c in db.Student_Course select new { SID = c.SID, Mark = c.Mark };

            editDataGridView.DataSource = studentCourse.ToList();
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            var student = (from s in db.Students select s).ToList();

            cboSID.DisplayMember = "SID";
            cboSID.ValueMember = "SID";
            cboSID.DataSource = student;
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            var course = (from c in db.Courses select c).ToList();

            cboCID.DisplayMember = "CID";
            cboCID.ValueMember = "CID";
            cboCID.DataSource = course;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are getting error because cboSID.Text is not the correct way to get selected value from combobox. Use cboSID.SelectedValue to select Student ID from combobox, cboCID.SelectedValue to select Course ID from combobox

Comment: That still doesn't fix it

Comment: Which code part is throwing this error.?!

Comment: Where I do the joining of the tables

Comment: remove db.SaveChanges() from the code,Because your just selecting some data from your db,So there is no need for using db.SaveChanges() there.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate more.

Comment: @vivekkv : sounds great, post it an answer

Comment: @VishalAnand So I've got two comboboxes called CID and SID where I can select the Course ID and Student ID. Then I have a textbox for Marks. I want to be able to select the Course ID and Student ID and then add the marks to it.

Comment: @Anon : So basically user will select Course ID and Student ID from the comboboxes and upon selection, text box will be populated with the corresponding marks that student (by student id)  had secured for that Couse ( by course Id ). Am I correct ?

Comment: @VishalAnand No, the user will have to input the marks into the textbox by themselves. The Student ID and Course ID and the new mark will be added to the Student_Course database.

Comment: Anon please check for inner exceptions and post it here if there is one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            int SID = Convert.ToInt32(cboSID.SelectedItem.ToString());
            int CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboCID.SelectedItem.ToString());  
            int got_marks = Convert.ToInt32(txtMark.Text);          

            Student_Course marks = db.Student_Course.Where(sc => sc.SID == SID && c.CID == CID ).FirstOrDefault();
            if( marks!= null ){
              marks.Mark = got_marks;
            }else{
               db.Student_Course.Add(new Student_Course{
                    SID = SID,
                    CID = CID,
                    Mark = got_marks
               });

            }


            db.SaveChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Marks Added");
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2()) //link combobox and DataGridView to List in Student_Course
        {
            var studentCourse = from c in db.Student_Course select new { SID = c.SID, Mark = c.Mark };

            editDataGridView.DataSource = studentCourse.ToList();
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            var student = (from s in db.Students select s).ToList();

            cboSID.DisplayMember = "SID";
            cboSID.ValueMember = "SID";
            cboSID.DataSource = student;
        }

        using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
        {
            var course = (from c in db.Courses select c).ToList();

            cboCID.DisplayMember = "CID";
            cboCID.ValueMember = "CID";
            cboCID.DataSource = course;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm adding the marks to the database, therefore it needs to be saved. And thanks Vishal. This worked!

Comment: @anon : No problem. Glad I was able to help :) You can also upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Entities2 db = new Entities2())
{
 int SID = Convert.ToInt32(cboSID.SelectedValue);//Change cboSID.Text to cboSID.SelectedValue
 int CID = Convert.ToInt32(cboCID.SelectedValue);//Change cboCID.Text to  cboCID.SelectedValue               
 Student_Course marks = (from c in db.Student_Course join s in db.Students on c.SID equals s.SID join o in db.Courses on c.CID equals o.CID where c.SID == SID && c.CID == CID select c).First();
 marks.Mark = Convert.ToInt32(txtMark.Text);
 //Delete this line db.SaveChanges();
 MessageBox.Show("Marks Added");
}
```

Comment: how does this answer the question ?

Comment: There is no change in the database because he is just selecting some data from the database so there is no need for db.SaveChanges(),This is only required when Some change is made into the database

Comment: Hey. It didn't help with the error I get when I try to join the tables.

Comment: @vivekkv : you are right about SaveChanges() but that is not what question is about and it will not throw any exception if added. EF will not send a query to DB in this case aswell.